# Make sure auto incremental ID is not in another table

Tags: mysql

Okay for various reasons I need to make sure an auto incremental ID is not in another table when it is inserted. So the `ID` in `table1` cannot be the same as the `ID` in `table2`. The `ID` in both tables must be auto incremented but the numbers cannot be the same as `ID` from both are inserted into another table with a trigger. I cannot have the auto incremental value set higher on one table than the other as that causes other problems.

My idea is to have a `WHERE` clause with a sub query in the auto increment part of the schema but I am not sure if that's possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: there are many similar questions here.. like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3030254/944681)

Comment: @MichalKlouda Seems simple and effective. But being new to this, what's a stub?

Comment: are you new to google as well? :) check this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_stub)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a trigger to check whether the next ID exists using `BEFORE INSERT`.

[This resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3334487/679449) will show you how to fetch the next `AUTO_INCREMENT` value and [this resource](http://momolog.info/2009/10/21/mysql-before-insert-trigger-as-check-constraint/) outlines how to create a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger. Hopefully these resources can get you on the right path.